# java setting array1 = tempArray

Tags: java, arrays

I am a C++ programmer learning java. In a method I want to do the following take an array of objects that exists inside the current object [referred to as array1], and replace it with a different array [tempArray] (example in form of c++ code)

```
$ ...
$15  private void replaceArray(){
$16      // exchanging values tempArray also has been generated in this omitted section
$17      delete[] array1;
$18      array1 = tempArray;
$19 }
$ ...
```

the issue that I am running into is that the keyword "delete" does not really exist in java. so my question is that if I only do...

```
$ ...
$15 private void replaceArray(){
$16     // exchanging values tempArray also has been generated in this omitted section
$17      array1 = tempArray;
$18 }
$ ...
```

will the original array1 still exist with no pointer to access it or will that be taken care of by the managed code environment of java (yes, I know that pointers still exist but the java virtual machine manages them only. with the programmer having no rights to touch them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct associations with arrays is similar to copy the pointer to the new variable.

If you have another var to tempArray and modify any value, the array1 you also be modified.

But if there's no reference to that array, the JVM will take care of the memory.

Also, the better way to copy a array is making a clone() of it.

Comment: the reason that clone()[?] won't work is that I am trying to copy every element in the array accept one, potentially in the middle. leading to not searching through information that does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector will take care of cleanup. This, and the lack of destructors, will likely be the most notable differences moving from c++ to java. You'll also need to come to terms with *every* object being a pointer - you can't put anything but built-in simple types and pointers on stack.

Answer (score 1):

After array1 points to tempArray you will no longer be able to reassign it to it's previous value. (assuming there is nothing else referencing it) The object that array1 originally pointed to will still exist in memory until the JVM does it's garbage collection to free up memory.